# Maximal elements in mapping

Tags: solidity

I wrote in solidity the following mapping:

```
mapping (uint => address) public RealEststeRegistry; //uint=assetID, address= OwnerAddress
```

I wonder, how many elements can I store in the RealEststeRegistry (after deployment of course)?

(I plan to use this mapping to backup some information I have in my database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart contracts use a key-value structure to store data. There are 2<sup>256</sup> keys, and each key can store 32 bytes, so that's a total of 2<sup>261</sup> bytes can be stored.

Let's say the size of address is 32 bytes (20 bytes actually), then you can store 2<sup>256</sup> addresses in a contract.